# framing in a new doorway and split out the bottom plate. now what?

Tags: framing

I framed in a new doorway on a load bearing wall.  All went well until i stupidly [image]decided to toenail the jack stud into the bottom plate, but after I had cut out the entry from the bottom plate.  the result was a split bottom plate.  I PVA glued and clamped it back together, but will the inspector be satisfied?  is there some sort of bracket I can use to fix this?  what other options do I have?

Answer (score 3):

Looks good, keep going. It will not be a problem.